# Do vertical mice cause less stress on the hand, wrist and arm than traditional mice?

Tags: computers, tendinopathy, ergonomics

Vertical mice are often marketed as more ergonomics than traditional mice. Is that true? I am especially interested in stress on the lateral epicondyle of the humerus.

Example of such claim, from https://evoluent.com/:

[image]

Comment: Wow, never knew those existed. Thanks. I've heard that the natural wrist/arm position is that of like when you are holding a glass of water in your hand. So these probably are a lot more ergonomic for you. If anything, it might not be a bad idea to use a mouse like this 5 days out of the week and a regular mouse the other 2 days, just to change it up.

Answer (score 5):

> **Carpal Tunnel Syndrome (CTS)** is numbness, tingling, weakness, and other problems in your hand because of pressure on a nerve (median
>   nerve) going through your wrist. [{1}](http://www.webmd.com/pain-management/carpal-tunnel/carpal-tunnel-syndrome-topic-overview)

Pressure or swelling of the median nerve causes CTS and making the same hand movements over and over may induce swelling. The swelling can get even worse if the wrist is bent down (your hands lower than your wrists) or by making the same wrist movements repeatedly.

The ergonomic mouse serves to prevent people from holding their mice on the edge of their desks or other surface, which naturally rests in a manner that bends the wrist. The person has to keep their wrist straight in order to use the mouse, thus reducing swelling over time.

It can be annoying to adjust to an ergonomic keyboard or mouse, but they help keep the wrists straight, which can be a problem for anyone sitting all day at a computer.

Given what an ergonomic mouse and keyboard are *supposed* to do, **there is little or no data to support the concept that activity adjustment** prevents carpal tunnel syndrome. The study cited below has results that are inconsistent and non-conclusive. The researchers even state in their conclusion:

> Speculative causal theories should be analyzed through a rigorous
>   approach prior to wide adoption.

[{The Quality and Strength of Evidence for Etiology: Example of Carpal Tunnel Syndrome }](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0363502308000087)

Comment: @kenorb Thanks for the edit! Looks better than before. :)